# Plot 3D function in R

Tags: r, function, plot

Is there a way how to plot function with 3 variable in R?

I know how to perform this in Matlab. But what about R?

I can easily plot 2 variables, but plotting 3 variables I dont know.

For example, if I want to plot `f(x,y,z) = 8x + xy + y^3 + z^3`.

Is there a way how to do so?  Can I tell if the function is convex or concave?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a function with several arguments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431555/plot-a-function-with-several-arguments-in-r)

Comment: There are several ways to visualize a function of 3 variables. This is not a quesiton about a particular software. You have to pick your way first. Take a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/visualize-plot-of-a-function-of-3-variables-using-color-and-contours).