# Plotting a function with points()

Tags: r, plot

I am using R to plot a function, and want to add lines describing multiple functions to the same plot. To plot a function, I write:

```
plot(function(x){x}, 
     xlab="Celsius", xlim=c(-100, 100), 
     ylab="Degrees", ylim=c(-100, 100))
```

This would plot a 1:1 line. If I want to **plot a different function on the same graph**, I can use the `points()` function but this requires data values for `x` to be provided such that it plots `length(x)` points (joined by lines) as:

```
points(x=seq(-100, 100, by=0.1), 
       y=c(seq(-100, 100, by=0.1)-32)*5/9, 
       typ="l", col="red")
```

**Is it possible to add lines to a plot when plotting a function rather than having to calculate data points using `points()` or another function?** Essentially, it would be something like this:

```
plot(function(x){x}, 
     xlab="Celsius", xlim=c(-100, 100), 
     ylab="Degrees", ylim=c(-100, 100))
points(function(x){(x-32)*5/9}, 
       typ="l", col="red")
```

*This is just an example, it shows the relationship between degrees Celsius on the X axis, and degrees on the Y axis in Celsius (black) and Fahrenheit (red). In reality I want to plot multiple complex functions but that would just add noise to the question.*

[image]

---

One solution I found is

```
plot(function(x){x}, 
     xlab="Celsius", xlim=c(-100, 100), 
     ylab="Degrees", ylim=c(-100, 100))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(function(x){(x-32)*5/9}, 
     xlab="", xlim=c(-100, 100), 
     ylab="", ylim=c(-100, 100),
     axes=FALSE, col="red")
```

But it seems cumbersome having to define limits and labels and `AXES=FALSE` each time.

Comment: If you want to plot functions, use the `curve` function.

Comment: You may find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431555/plot-a-function-with-several-arguments-in-r) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `plot` function twice and add `add = TRUE` for the second plot.

With `plot`, you can also use `from` and `to` parameters to avoid repeating the y-axis limits, although it will keep the y-axis limits defined in the first plot (so it might not be optimal).

```
plot(function(x){x}, 
     xlab="Celsius", xlim=c(-100, 100), 
     ylab="Degrees", ylim=c(-100, 100))
plot(function(x) {(x-32)*5/9}, from = -100, to = 100, typ="l", col="red", add=T)
```

[image: example]

As mentioned by @Roland and @user2554330, you can also use `curves` if you want to plot multiple lines from the same function, and use `()` to avoid assigning the function beforehand, with `add = i!=1` standing for `add = T` at every iteration except the first one.

```
for(y in 1:10) {
  curve((x + 10*y), from=-100, to=100, add=i!=1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that - I get a good solution as `celsius <- function(x){x}; farenheit <- function(x){(x-32)*5/9}; curve(celsius(x), (from <- -100), (to <- 100)); curve(farenheit(x), from, to, add=TRUE, col="red");` - would be nice not to have to assign the function first but this will do in terms of improving the code

Comment: You don't have to assign the function.  With `plot()` you can use an anonymous function, with `curve()` you can use an expression containing `x` (but not just `x`, use `(x)` for that).  Don't use `(from <- -100)`, use `from = -100`; they aren't the same thing!  e.g. `curve((x), from=-100, to=100); curve((x-32)*5/9, add=TRUE)`.

Comment: Did not know that, but very useful; I'm gonna edit my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @user2554330 I know they are not the same thing. The use of `(from <- -100)` is to make the code dynamic: I only need to adjust one piece of code to adjust all of the curves - it's just a variable called `from` and I could equally use `start` or any other variable name, I chose `from` so that the code is easy to read.

Comment: The `from` and `to` arguments are ignored when `add = TRUE`, so no need to repeat them.